# On Suitable Margins, Text Dimensions, and Font Size for Foolscap Octavo

Tags: margins, geometry, book-design, octavo

I have been asked to produce a geometrically small book.

Tentatively, I am considering a Foolscap Octavo book size; that is, dimensions 4.25'' x 6.75''.

However, I am not familiar with working on such small books.

So, to get an idea of a basic layout of such a book, I ran the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,foolscap]{octavo}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=4.25in,paperheight=6.75in]{geometry}
% margin=.75in
\usepackage[frame,noinfo,center]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\small
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

which produced

[image]

[image]

Unless I am thinking iuncorrectly---I am surprised by some of the default margins.

For instance, the odd and even-side margins.

I am under the impression that by convention, odd-numbered pages appear on the right-hand side of a two-page layout and even-numbered pages appear on the left. If that is correct, then why is the left-hand side margin on page 1 appear to be smaller than the same side margin on page 2? In other words, why is the `oddsidemargin` less than the `evensidemargin`?---I am under the impression that if I specify `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin`---both refer to the left-hand margin of the relevant pages.

If there my reasoning is incorrect, please correct it.

QUESTION: For a foolscap octavo book paperwidth=4.25in and paperheight=6.75in, what are (or, might be) appropriate values for `textwidth`, `textheight`, `oddsidemargin`, and `evensidemargin`? Also,   though in the MWE, I specified `\documentclass[10pt,foolscap]{octavo}` and font size `\small` in the document itself, the size of the font on the screen still appears to me to be rather large---but that perhaps, is an optical illusion. Please suggest if any of these values might be changed as well.

Thank you.

Comment: "why is the left-hand side margin on page 1 appear to be smaller than the same side margin on page 2?" it is. perhaps if you open a spread (even page + odd page) you'll see that the middle (inner) margins together amount at least to, and maybe more than, each one of the outer ones.

Comment: don't use `\small` as a global document size, that will just make it inconvenient to set up heading fonts and spacing, and floats as they are set up for `\normalsize`  If you want `\normalsize` to be 9pt set up the class to define that, along with matching smaller fonts for `\small`  aad larger fonts for `\large` etc

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Many thanks for the advice.

Comment: See https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb23-3-4/tb75revets.pdf for an account of the typographical considerations in `octavo`.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you for providing this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get is the traditional printed book layout. Open a typical book between two pages and you will see two columns of text, one on the left hand (verso) page and the other on the right hand (recto ) page. The space before the left hand text is the same as the space after the right hand text and the space between the two texts is also the same. Resulting in two columns of text with equal space before, between, and after them.

This is the default LaTeX layout. If you want something else than the `memoir` manual, chapter "Laying out the page" provides much more detail.

If you are unhappy I suggest you read about book typography.

Bottom line, though, unless you really know what you are doing do not change the defaults.